# Optaplanner not using different values for PlanningVariable

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying implement a job shop scheduling application using Fisher & Thompson mt10 dataset. Basically it contains of

- 10 jobs, each having 10 dependent steps
- 10 machines
- each step of a job is assigned to a specific machine

I have implemented an Optaplanner use case based on the "Taskassigning" example. I removed the speed and priority concepts but kept the skill concept to make jobs run only on machines where they are able to run. I introduced a "predecessor" concept to build the dependencies between jobs/steps.

As there will be gaps in the schedule (which is different from the Taskassigning example), removed starttime and endtime and introduced a starttime PlanningVariable, fed by a list of possible start times.

However, I only get two different start times in the schedule - Optaplanner does not seem to utilize my value range provider. Therefore, hard constraints are violated because the sequence of dependent steps is not kept.

Job:

```
private JobType jobType;
private Job predecessor;
private Job successor;
private int indexInJobType;

// Planning variables: changes during planning, between score calculations.
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"machineRange", "jobRange"},
        graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
private JobOrMachine previousJobOrMachine;

@AnchorShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousJobOrMachine")
private Machine machine;

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"startTimeRange"})
private StartTime startTime=new StartTime(0); // In minutes
```

My PlanningSolution has a range provider:

```
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "startTimeRange")
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
public List<StartTime> getStartTimeList() {
    return startTimeList;
}
```

I am relatively new to Optaplanner and might be missing something very basic. I am struggling to identify what I am doing wrong, even after extensive reading of the docs and examples.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem with a hard constraint rule related to the planning variable. This question is no longer valid. Thanks.